# Ajax animation on select tag

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I'm searching for visual animation during an AJAX call. But I want an animation on a select html tag, not on the whole page.

Is this possible to do?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you mean a `<select>` tag or a select tag; as in any tag you choose in the HTML?

Comment: i mean `<select>` tag yeah

Comment: I have updated my answer to demo my idea using a `<select>` tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I were to do this I would use CSS to create a helper class to show and hide the ajax loader (either as a background-image or as an icon). Then I would set that class before my ajax call then remove it on the callback.

Here is a demo of what I am talking about (I will use Font Awesome for the ajax loader).

HTML

```
<button>Submit<i class="fa fa-circle-o-notch fa-spin"></i></button>
```

CSS

```
button{
    position:relative;
    padding:6px 32px;
    border:0;
    background:#42c827;
    color:#fff;
}

button i{
    position:absolute;
    top:7px;
    right:8px;
    opacity:0;
}

button.busy i{
    opacity:1;
}
```

JavaScript

```
$(function(){

    $('button').on('click', function(e){
       e.preventDefault();
        var btn = $(this);
        btn.addClass('busy');

        //simulate ajax call
        setTimeout(function(){
            btn.removeClass('busy');
        }, 2000);

    });

});
```

See it in action in this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qqa5z9kx/).

**UPDATE**

For a `<select>` tag the markup is a bit different but the idea is the same. Instead you place the loader next to the `<select>` instead of inside it and give them an outer wrapper.

See this [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mh58Lbjz/) for a demo using a `<select>` tag.

Comment: nice i will deal with your tip

Answer (score 0):

You can use jQuery `ajaxStart` and `ajaxStop` handlers to make something during AJAX.

```
$( document ).ajaxStart(function() {
    $(".preloader").show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

not inside the select tag but the animation can be placed near by to the it. 
I do such animations like that..

    ..

and this is the js:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#refresh').click(function(){
    //show the animation here
    $('#animation_place').html("<img src='loading_anim.gif'/>");
    $.ajax({
    //write your url and type and the othre things here..
    success:function(data){
    //Bind the select tag with the new data
    $('#animation_place').html(""); //clear the animation..
    }
    });
    });
    });
```